# When calling my function, it doesn't work?

Tags: python, function

I'm taking Computer Science for GCSE and we have a project due, but I can't seem to figure out how to work functions. It tells me that "NameError: name 'option1' is not defined" and even when I define it, it doesn't seem to work. If you could check the code below and tell me how to fix things, explaining how and why it didn't work, I'd be super grateful! Thanks!
( For now please do ignore the register and leaderboard functions, I'll figure those out myself one I understand how the Login function should work. )

```
##### login, register or see the leaderboard.
def option():
    option1 = int(input("""Would you like to:
    1. Login
    2. Register
    3. See the Leaderboard"""))

##### MAIN CODE
while choice == True:
    option()

    if option1 == 1:
        login()
        choice = False

    elif option1 == 2:
        register()
        choice = False

    elif option1 == 3:
        leaderboardopen()
        choice = False

    else:
        print("Incorrect value given. Please try again.")
```

Comment: this is an issue of scopes. the variable option1 only exists inside the `option` function's block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Robert and Paritosh mentioned above the `option1` doesn't exist outside of the `option` function. I can suggest the following solution:

```
def option():
    return int(input("Would you like to:"))

##### MAIN CODE
while choice == True:
    option1 = option()
    if option1 == 1:
        login()
    # continue your logic
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return the chosen option and capture the returned value in your main code:

```
##### login, register or see the leaderboard.
def option():
    option1 = int(input("""Would you like to:
    1. Login
    2. Register
    3. See the Leaderboard"""))
    return option1

##### MAIN CODE
choice = True
while choice == True:
    option1 = option()

    if option1 == 1:
        login()
        choice = False

    elif option1 == 2:
        register()
        choice = False

    elif option1 == 3:
        leaderboardopen()
        choice = False

    else:
        print("Incorrect value given. Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `choice`. Also you are declaring `option1` inside a function, so when you are out of that function it is not defined. Try this, you need to return something from the function.

```
##### login, register or see the leaderboard.

choice = True

def option():
    option = int(input("""Would you like to:
    1. Login
    2. Register
    3. See the Leaderboard"""))
    return option

##### MAIN CODE
while choice == True:
    option = option()
    if option == 1:
        login()
        choice = False

    elif option == 2:
        register()
        choice = False

    elif option == 3:
        leaderboardopen()
        choice = False

    else:
        print("Incorrect value given. Please try again.")
```